# Most silent way to kill someone

Tags: modern-age

What is the most silent way for my antagonist to kill people? The assasin aproaches people in their private spaces in order to terminate them but he doesn't want other people to hear anything.

Comment: You need gear from [Tomorrow Technology Today](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0138.html).

Comment: Cancer, but he needs to be patient.

Comment: There's no end of ways to kill people silently ranging from sniper rifle at 1000+ yards to crushing wind pipes at zero yards.  WB SE is not for "idea shopping", but even ignoring this your question is extremely broad.

Comment: This is an exceptionally poor question by the sites rules, you're basically asking us to come up with ideas & tell you how which makes it far too broad & opinion based, the question could be improved by outlining what you intend your character to do & asking if it's plausible but even then it would almost certainly still be primarily opinion based & it's hard to see how it would really be about world building even then.

Comment: Drop a city-sized asteroid upon them. It will kill most species on the planet regardless of who may or may not hear it. It might be tad on the expensive side, but it gets results!

Answer (score 4):

With due credit to Tom Clancy (from *Teeth of the Tiger*), injecting succinylcholine will kill silently and almost undetectably.  It blocks acetylcholine receptors, inhibiting all voluntary muscles, producing almost instant complete paralysis, including breathing cessation.  The victim will die in minutes of suffocation -- *and the poison will be metabolized by the victim's body after death*.

Injection may be intramuscular (the assassin need not be able to find a vein, just jab and push), and it would take a blood sample to be drawn within minutes of death to have any chance of detection even by a coroner or investigator *who knew what to look for*.

If this level of technology isn't available, the same novel gave a "low tech" version -- inserting a thin, long-bladed knife between the first cervical vertebra and the skull and severing the spinal cord will have the same effect, with a wound that will bleed little.  This would be obvious to any competent investigator, but if the assassin keeps the knife, almost equally untraceable.

Comment: Do note that surprise spontaneous suffocation in healthy individuals without signs of a struggle is something that investigators will find Quite Suspicious. Forensic techniques [do exist](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27179645) for detecting the relevant metabolites.

Answer (score 0):

**Vacuum.**

In order for sound to travel it requires a medium to travel, commonly air, the medium through which we hear music, highways and less commonly screams.

The only way to ensure absolute silence is to withdraw the air. A maximum of 15 Seconds to unconsciousness, all the while the moisture from the tongue, nasal mucosa, the lungs and the eyeballs evaporating causing disorienting sensations.

Although it rather depends on what "private spaces" you are referring to: be-it space station (which we have in the modern era) or laboratory (many of which have hermetic seals to prevent contamination) bear in mind, modern double glazing on patio-doors and windows, and we've recently got on our front door are (probably for the story's sake) capable of retaining sufficient vacuum to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily about silence per se, it's about not making a sound that will be noticed. Hence, suppressed firearms are not inaudible, but the sound does not register with bystanders as a gunshot so an assassin can use one without attracting attention.

Simply coshing someone over the head will not be noticed by someone in the next room if done quickly and decisively with a single blow.

If you want something a bit fancier, then a rifle-caliber air rifle - like the military-grade Girandoni air gun, or the one used by Conan Doyle's Colonel Moran would do nicely.